# Angular dropdown list when the list is opened, it is display under the following div

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I am using mat-select to display a dropdown list. If there is no element after the dropdown, it is displayed correctly but when I add a div containing a map, the label will stay at the same place but the list is displayed under the map. Is there a way to whether display the list in front of the map? or at least move the map down?

Comment: Can you provide a sample code

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided the code or screenshot, what I can think of is some issue caused by z-index conflicts.

Have you tried to increase the z-index of the select? Something like:

```
.cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-overlay-pane {
     z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Put the above code in the global CSS.